# loadTs is not a function

Tags: graphql-codegen

After running `graphql-codegen-esm --config codegen.yml` the following message is shown in the console

```
loadTs is not a function
```

I add files with my project configuration

package.json

```json
{
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"nodemon\" \"npm run codegen --watch\"",
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen-esm --config codegen.yml"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@graphql-tools/load-files": "^6.6.0",
    "apollo-server": "^3.10.0",
    "graphql": "^16.5.0",
    "graphql-modules": "^2.1.0",
    "graphql-scalars": "^1.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/add": "^3.2.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "2.11.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/graphql-modules-preset": "^2.5.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-resolvers": "^2.7.2",
    "@tsconfig/node18-strictest-esm": "^1.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

codegen.yml

```yaml
schema: './src/**/*.graphql'
emitLegacyCommonJSImports: false
generates:
  ./src/graphql/:
    preset: graphql-modules
    presetConfig:
      baseTypesPath: ../generated-types/graphql.ts # Where to create the complete schema types
      filename: generated-types/module-types.ts # Where to create each module types
    plugins:
      - add:
          content: '/* eslint-disable */'
      - typescript
      - typescript-resolvers
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18-strictest-esm/tsconfig.json",
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Node

```
v18.7.0
```